# Mostrar resultados diferentes dependiendo del campo

Tags: base-de-datos, oracle

Estoy haciendo una consulta que quiero que me retornen los números de celular de la siguiente manera:

código_pais + codigo_area + numero_telefono

El problema que tengo es que algunos numero_telefono estan cargados con '15' adelante y otros sin el '15' adelante. Lo intente hacerlo con un case, pero no logro hacerlo complicar y solo muestro los que empiezan con 15.

```
    select 
      case when substr(c_nro_tlefono,0,2) = '15' 
      then '549'||c_cod_area||substr(c_nro_tlefono,3,99)
    from t_vis_gen_telefonos
```

Estoy usando oracle.

Comment: y que quieres hacer con el 15 delante???

Comment: que no salga en el resultado

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Efectivamente, puedes solucionar tu problema usando una estructura [CASE](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/expressions004.htm)

Ten en cuenta que todo *case* tiene su *end*.

Tu consulta quedaría correcta de la siguiente forma:

```
select 
case when substr(c_nro_tlefono,0,2) = '15' 
     then '549'||c_cod_area||substr(c_nro_tlefono,3,99)
     else  '549'||c_cod_area||c_nro_tlefono
end 
from t_vis_gen_telefonos;
```

Con *else* muestras todos los demás teléfonos que no comiencen con '15'

Comment: Gracias me funciono correctamente